# Переполнение типа данных в тесте Ферма на простоту

Tags: c#, алгоритм, простые-числа

Добрый день. Реализовал вероятностный алгоритм определение простоты числа на основе малой теоремы Ферма. Однако, есть проблема, что тип при даже 11-значном числе, переполняется. Вопрос как можно элегантно решить эту проблему не используя BigInteger? 
Сам метод

```
public static ulong IsPrimeNumb(ulong n, ulong a)
    {
        ulong e = 1, b=a;
        for (var i = n; i > 0;)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                e = (e * b) % n;                    
            }

            b = (b * b) % n;
            i /= 2;
        }
        return e == a ? n : 0; 
    }
```

Comment: если тебе нужны большие числа, почему бы не использовать специальный класс?

Comment: @Grundy просто интересно как это можно реализовать еще.

Comment: ну вы можете написать свою реализацию длинной арифметики вместо BigInteger, на сколько это будет элегантно зависит от вас

Comment: Вобщем,  я пока не знаю как, но мне кажется нужно найти способ откидывать разряды больше максимального разряда проверяемого числа +1. Но как это делать во время умножения я пока не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

```
e = (e * b) % n;
b = (b * b) % n;
```

> Произведение чисел  при делении на некоторое число дает тот же
>   остаток, что и произведение их остатков.
>
> Например, посчитаем остаток 107*207 по модулю 4. Числа 107 и 207 при
>   делении на 4 дают  остаток 3, если перемножить эти остатки получится
>   9. А 9 при делении на 4 дает остаток 1, значит,  и 107*207 дает остаток 1.

```
e = ((e % n) * (b % n)) % n;
b = ((b % n) * (b % n)) % n;
```

Теперь переполнения быть не должно.
Что касается типов данных, то можно использовать [decimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal), если тебе просто не хватает разрядов для входных значений.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но это не поможет в случае, когда делитель больше частного.
Пример. 

99 % 100 == 99 и 
78 % 100 == 78

при их переумножении произойдет переполнение стека и я не смогу посчитать остаток.

Comment: @AndreyKhristoforov при умножении 99 на 78 ты совершенно точно не получаешь переполнение (не стека ;)), максимальное значение, которое может принять decimal:  79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335, соответственно оба множителя должны быть в пределах 281,474,976,710,655
Должно хватить для делителя. :D

Comment: Там в цикле и так выполняется `%n` и для `e`, и для `b`, так что это в данном случае ничего не даст.

Comment: @Harry не говори ерунды, `(b * b) % n` и `((b % n) * (b % n)) % n` - это числа совершенно разного порядка. В первом случае ты умножаешь два 11-значных числа, во втором - остатки от деления.

Comment: @LunarWhisper Посмотри на цикл - в нем в цикле вычисления построены так, что `b = (b * b) % n` - что после этого даст твое `b%n`? Если `b` **уже** меньше `n`? Аналогично и `e` вычисляется так же - как `e = (e * b) % n;`, так что при входе на следующую итерацию и `e`, и `n` **уже** меньше `n`. Дошло или повторить медленнее? Посмотри мой комментарий - я четко написал "в данном случае", и пояснил, почему.

Comment: @LunarWhisper harry прав. Дело в том, что до умножения там уже остатки, то есть чилсо меньше n. Поэтому операция остаток от деления ничего не даст.

Comment: @AndreyKhristoforov, @Harry я не знаю, как вы читаете это код, но я вижу для первой итерации: `e = 1`, `b = 99999999999999`, `b = 99999999999999 * 99999999999999`
На второй и последующих итерациях - да, там остатки. На первой - исходное значение `a`, что и приводит к фейлу.